# "A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?" on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded phpMyAdmin to latest version some days ago following a tutorial from a site (deleting and replacing all the content of phpMyAdmin folder in Xampp and replacing with latest one and placing old `config.inc.php` again). After upgrading, I frequently get the error message and error code.

```
         {
"exception": {
    "mode": "onerror",
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: makeProfilingChart is not defined",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": "1",
            "func": "?",
            "uri": "sql.php?target=",
            "scriptname": "sql.php"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36",
    "uri": "sql.php?target="
},
"script_name": "sql.php",
"pma_version": "4.1.7",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "32.0.1700.107",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "enabled",
"php_version": "5.5.6",
"microhistory": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "hash": "index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=9e78f35e781e58d1a3a46f930985af27"
        },
        {
            "hash": "db_structure.php?db=widget_crop&table=&server=1&target=&token=9e78f35e781e58d1a3a46f930985af27",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "querywindow_height": "400",
                "querywindow_width": "600",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "confirm": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "hash": "sql.php?db=widget_crop&table=users&server=1&target=&token=9e78f35e781e58d1a3a46f930985af27",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "querywindow_height": "400",
                "querywindow_width": "600",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "confirm": "true"
            }
        }
    ],
    "current_index": "3"
}
}
```

I can't revert back to the old version since I already deleted it, the error cause no response to mouse click and I stuck in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also have an error message ("A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?") in Chrome browser. I try 'localhost/phpmyadmin' in Internet Explorer, it work well. So I disable PageXray extension in Chrome browser. It's work well with Chrome browser. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is with Chrome browser when certain extensions are installed. For my case it was PageXray. Disabled the PageXray extension and phpmyadmin works fine and loads faster too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Google Chrome last update. This problem occurs in other jQuery and other codes. I suggest you use Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem for Chrome browser. I too faced this issue on my localhost when I tried accessing phpmyadmin and I had PageXray extension installed as well. So if you are using PageXray extension for Chrome and want to get rid of this error without removing PageXray extension, then do this:

- Right click on the PageXray icon which would be placed on address bar of Chrome (as seen in screenshot1)
- Hover over "This can read and change site data" dropdown and select the option "When you click the extension"
- Now you will be able to access phpmyadmin and other features without any problem.

The only difference it will make is that now you will need to click the PageXray extension icon everytime you want to check the technology stack being used on the website.

Screenshot 1:
[image: Screenshot: set PageXray extension option to remove the error on phpmyadmin panel]

Comment: This solution works only for chrome and also requires an extension for chrome - so it is no general solution for the problem.

Comment: @PowerStat but this problem is coming in Chrome browser only and it is browser specific. Please remove your downvote as this kind of gesture demotivates fellow StackOverflow users from contributing :(

I am editing my answer to accommodate your suggestion about general solution

Comment: Within the original question I can't read anything about chrome.