# PHP not inserting into database on MAMP phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mamp

`index.php`:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
            Comments: <input type="text" name="field1_name"/>
            <input type="Submit" /></form>
```

This takes in user input and I want whatever the user inputs to be stored in a database that I have using MAMP's phpmyadmin.

`insert.php`:

```
$user = 'x';
$password = '';
$db = 'comment_schema';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
$field1_name = ($_POST['field1_name']);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$password,$db,$port);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO parentComment(ID,Comment) VALUES('ID','$field1_name')");
```

The database table I have is named `parentComment` and the two columns are `ID` and `Comment`. I have `ID` set that so it automatically increments in my database.

When I try typing in something in my comments form, it gets updated in my database because a new row shows up with an `ID` however the comment doesn't get stored. So, it's doing something but it's not storing the comment for some reason. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

[image]

That's how my parentComment table looks like. The current error I'm getting is:

> A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?

I reported the error though so it hasn't been showing up. I don't know if that's part of the problem.

Comment: Can you post an image of your database structure?

Comment: Try echoing `$field1_name` to see the value

Comment: i echoed and nothing prints out. so i'm assuming it's just not recognizing the variable

Comment: Then something's wrong with `$_POST['field1_name']`. Did you fill up this input - `<input type="text" name="field1_name"/>`?

Comment: yeah I have. I have the html code in the question as well but I'm pretty sure that part is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `ID` field value is autogenerated so you have no need trying to declare it explicitly in the insert statement. So you should change insert query to this:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO parentComment(Comment) VALUES('$field1_name')");
```

Comment: I actually tried this, and it still doesn't work :( I'm getting an error however in my phpadmin site where it says javascript error. Not sure if there's a problem with that?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the error info that you are getting? Also, it would be nice to have a look at the `parentComment` table creation DDL.

Comment: @OviyaArasu You haven't posted any Javascript code. Is the error still related to the `insert.php` file?

Comment: that's the thing, there is not javascript code. I get that error on my phpadmin page. I think the error is on the insert.php file related to the $field1_name

Comment: I'm confused. Firstly, You have asked about comments storing: '_So, it's doing something but it's not storing the comment for some reason. Not sure where I'm going wrong_'. But now we are talking about phpMyAdmin.

Comment: yeah sorry forget about the phpadmin. I just realized that's an issue, however I do think the problem is with the storing. I just think maybe that the phpadmin may have some issue as well. I just don't really have an idea where the error is coming from really. trust me im just as confused.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not aware of how data is written into the database. That's something completely different and required different information, such as browser version and javascript console log, at least.

Comment: ok so the problem is with the actual sql or html code i've written then?

Comment: No, completely not! Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758084/a-fatal-javascript-error-has-occurred-would-you-like-to-send-an-error-report about phpMyAdmin Javascript error

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Sorry I believe my statement below is incorrect.**

I believe there is at least an error in your query where you are using the `$field1_name` variable. You are treating it the same as the ID (string) when it is a variable.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO parentComment(ID,Comment) VALUES('ID','.$field1_name.')");
```

Whether this will fix your issue or not I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you maked ID auto increment you don't need to assign its value.Try this-

```
$field1_name = $_POST['field1_name'];
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO parentComment(id,Comment) VALUES('','$field1_name')");
```

Comment: Your query still assigns a value to the `id` column. It's an empty string in your case. To insert default value for the column (which will be autogenerated) must not declare the column at all.

Answer (score 0):

And for the javascript error its only in chrome
I also had that error message ("A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?") in Chrome browser. I tried 'localhost/phpmyadmin' in Internet Explorer, it work well. So disable PageXray extension in Chrome browser from help of stackoverflow. and it worked for me